# Accessing meteor server on LAN

Tags: node.js, meteor, lan

I'm currently using Reaction Commerce (https://github.com/ongoworks/reaction) on my Ubuntu VM but I'm unable to view it anywhere else on my LAN. When I launch the server I get a simple "App running at http://*local*:3000" but when I try to access this from another PC on the LAN (http://*local IP*:3000) I am redirected to that PCs localhost which isn't running anything.

I've tried changing the settings file and Dockerfile to read 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost but it seems to make little difference as meteor continuously says the localhost is still being used.

Any insight on what exactly needs to be changed would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `force-ssl` package. In the app's working directory:

```
meteor remove force-ssl
```

This will stop it redirecting. (Mean't to force everyone not using 127.0.0.1 or localhost onto the ROOT_URL with https)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling to figure this out, I can't believe I missed this in the documentation.