# Meteor app on local network

Tags: meteor

I'm learning how to use Meteor by following [the tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/try). I'm aware that Meteor automatically hosts the app to both `localhost` and my IPv4 address (in this instance, `192.168.1.100`). When I visit `192.168.1.100:3000` on the computer it's hosted from, the app works fine, however it won't load on any other devices that access `192.168.1.100:3000` from the local network.

I've read the following answers:

- [Accessing meteor server on LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195821/accessing-meteor-server-on-lan)
- [Accessing Meteor local web server from another local device on Mac 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601961/accessing-meteor-local-web-server-from-another-local-device-on-mac-10-8)
- [Meteor - accessing the app using public ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276097/meteor-accessing-the-app-using-public-ip)
- [How to run meteor server on a different ip address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123633/how-to-run-meteor-server-on-a-different-ip-address)
- [Start Meteor server and let other computers access it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712782/start-meteor-server-and-let-other-computers-access-it)

And none of them worked for me. It may be because I'm running Windows. If that's the case, can anyone help on how to host the app on the local network?

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of reasons why you may not be able to

try opening the port

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Meteor 3000" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=3000
```

if connecting via wifi, then routers often disallow connections to other devices on the network, check router settings

Comment: The command executed ok, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: are you doing it over wifi?

Comment: on my system, didn't have to do anything fancy, just ran meteor ( just default, on localhost:3000 ).  Opened the port,  worked fine from other things on the LAN (not the wifi )

Comment: I have my computer hooked up to the router by an Ethernet cable, if that makes any difference.

Comment: what about the device that's trying to get to your computer?