# Access Meteor server on LAN

Tags: meteor

I try to run the meteor server and access on LAN but not successful.

On server: access by localhost:3000 is ok.
But from other PC on LAN, when I access by http://server_IP:3000 I found in load HTML code
"base href="http://localhost:3000/"
so the webbrowser keep connect localhost, can't continue load other packages.

I search and tried to set environment:
    ROOT_URL=http://server_ip:3000/ meteor
or
    meteor --port server_ip:3000
but there is no change.

Could you please instruct me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you already tried to search on SO? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29761000/5847906) helpful?

Comment: Thanks, but I found my problem. In the my html code, my colleague fix the link as localhost:3000. After change that, it's ok now

Comment: Feel free to delete your question or answer it yourself.